# SQL result duplicates the photos

Tags: sql, join, pdo, duplicates

I want to show all the photos that have the specific tag, but it only duplicates the photos. If I choose another tag, it doesn't show duplicated photos.

[image: duplicated photos]
[image: not duplicated photos]

For the tag "Natur" it should only be 2 photos and for the tag "Berg" it should only be 1 photo.

**SQL**

```
SELECT *
FROM photos AS p
JOIN tags_photos AS tp
JOIN tags_names AS tn
ON tp.id_tag = tn.id
WHERE tn.data_name_seo = :name_seo
ORDER BY p.datetime_taken DESC
```

**Database: tags_photos**

```
id
id_photo
id_tag
```

**Database: tags_name**

```
id
data_name
data_name_seo
```

**Database: photos**

```
id
data_file_name
datetime_taken
```

Have I missed something or what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing join conditions for the first two tables.  This is probably the cause of your problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM photos AS p JOIN
     tags_photos AS tp
     ON tp.id_photo = p.id JOIN
     tags_names AS tn
     ON tp.id_tag = tn.id
WHERE tn.data_name_seo = :name_seo
ORDER BY p.datetime_taken DESC
```

In most databases, the missing `on` clause would generate an error.  In MySQL, the `JOIN` is treated as a `CROSS JOIN`, which likely would result in duplicates.

Comment: Many thanks! It was that I've missed. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can :)